# c++ stream manipulator that inserts a multi-character delimiter if stream is not empty

Tags: c++, templates, std

I am using the `delimiter` manipulator below to insert a comma or a space to separate items when writing them into a stringstream. Is there a way to make it support multi-character separators as well ?

```
template <char C>
std::basic_ostream<char>& delimiter(std::basic_ostream<char>& os)                                                      
{
    if (os.tellp())
        os << C;
    return os;
}

std::stringstream ss;
if (pid) ss << delimiter<','> << "pid=" << pid;
if (gid) ss << delimiter<','> << "gid=" << gid;
```

The context here is building a string with comma-delimited stats, some of which may not be available (like PID, GID, etc). I'm trying to avoid having a comma as the first character in the stream. And `boost::join(list, ", ")` is more cumbersome, I'd prefer to output directly to the stream instead of a temporary list which I then join at the end.

Comment: you mean multicharacter template argument? (or is passing as function argument an option?)

Comment: The standard [stream buffer class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) doesn't have a public function that allows you to check if something have been written to it.

Comment: Looks like you are trying place some functionality in wrong place. Please provide more context so we can point you to correct place. Serialization process should not depend on internal state of stream (except when handling errors).

Comment: The context here is building a string with comma-delimited stats, some of which may not be available (like PID, GID, etc). I'm trying to avoid having a comma as the first character in the stream. And `boost::join(list, ", ")` is more cumbersome, I'd prefer to output directly to the stream instead of a temporary list which I then join at the end.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai: if `basic_ostream` supports manipulators defined as callable objects, then that is probably an option.

Comment: @Some programmer dude: true, I am using `delimiter()` opportunistically with `stringstream` and `ostringstream` which have`tellp()`. If I can define the template as to only accept these types, that would be preferable.

Comment: This breaks once you do something like `ss << "Properties: "; if (pid) ss << delimiter<','> << "pid: " << pid;` Use a stateful object in the style of `std::setw(n)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not overengeener things. In this case I do not see raeson to make complex delimiter.

```cpp
std::stringstream ss;
if (pid) ss << "pid=" << pid;
if (gid) {
    if (!pid) ss << ',';
    ss << "gid=" << gid;
}
```

2. Writing serialization code which depends on state of stream is fragile and hard to maintain. You should not hide information from other developer. If you relay like to make this kind of logic you can place more safe place:

```cpp
template <char delim>
class skip_first_delimiter {
    mutable bool was_used = false;

    template <char d>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const skip_first_delimiter<d>&);
};

template <char delim>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const skip_first_delimiter<delim>& d)
{
    if (!d.was_used) [[unlikely]] {
        d.was_used = true;
    } else {
        out << delim;
    }
    return out;
};

        auto delimiter = skip_first_delimiter<','> {};
        if (pid)
            std::cout << delimiter << "pid=" << pid;
        if (gid)
            std::cout << delimiter << "gid=" << gid;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/djYh68zW7

3. if this is some common data format, maybe there is a library which will do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can `delim<char...>` easily; syntax is `delim<',',' '>`, which sucks.

Modern C++ has user defined non type template arguments.  Look for a compile time string implementation.  They store an array inside themselves, and use looks like `delim<auto>` and `delim<", "_cts>`.

A less hacky solution is to write a continuation passing style join: `join(", ", foos, [&](auto&& x){os<<x;})`.  This can be extended to adding a `operator<<` and `os<<join(", ", foos)` which streams them in the callback directly out.

We can also do this at iteration time:

```
if(!foo.empty())
  os<<foo.front();
for(auto f:without_front(foo)){
  os<<", "<<f;
}
```

using a range adapter.

My personal range toy would do:

```
for(auto f:range(foo).only_front())
  os<<f;
for(auto f:range(foo).without_front())
  os<<", "<<f
```

for symmetry.  (The range-wrapper takes a container or range, makes a copy if and only if it is an rvalue, and is otherwise `const`.  `only_front(n)` and `without_front(n)` and `without_front()` modify the range in an efficient and end-checking-safe manner, and similarly for `_back` methods.  I believe the ranges TS has a similar bit of code).